# Salesforce Authentication with nodejs app

Tags: node.js

I have created nodejs  app and authenticated salesforce object. Account  by nodejs app.Here is link from where I took reference
https://docs.omniref.com/js/npm/nforce/0.0.2
Here is my code: Here is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var xFrameOptions = require('x-frame-options')
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var nforce = require('nforce');
var oauth;
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var socket = io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { });
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');
var org = nforce.createConnection({ 
  clientId: "XXXXXX",
  clientSecret: "XXXXXX",
  redirectUri: 'XXXXXX',
  apiVersion: 'v27.0',
  environment: 'sandbox',
  mode: 'single'
});
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5005);
org.authenticate({ username: “XXX”, password: “XXX”}, function(err, resp){

    var accounts = org.query({ query: 'select Id, Name from Account limit 20' }, function(err, resp){
    console.log(err);
    if(!err && resp.records) {
        resp.records.forEach(function(account) {
        console.log(account);       
        });
    }
    //socket.emit('news', resp);
    });
});
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
     console.log('see options '+request.session);
  response.render('pages/home',{user:"John Smith"});
});

server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
});
```

Here is home.hjs

```
<html><head><title>{{ user }}</title>
  </head>
  <form>
  <body >  
     <div id="future"></div>
    <iframe src="https://mcnabb--devsanbox--c.cs41.visual.force.com/apex/MyCart" height="400" width="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
 </body>
 </form> 
</html>
```

I want to open the  https:/XXX/apex/MyCart in the 
 Iframe. Although  authentication in server.js file is working but  unable to open "https://mcnabb--devsanbox--c.cs41.visual.force.com/apex/MyCart" display in 
Iframe in home.hjs.
Could  anyone help me out  in this.

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: when i logged in salesforce then i am able to open the display in my app but when i logged out of salesforce i got error

Comment: Refused to display 'https://mcnabb--devsanbox.cs41.my.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fvisual…3A%252F%252Fmcnabb--devsanbox--c.cs41.visual.force.com%252Fapex%252FMyCart' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Answer (score 4):

This is to prevent iFrame [Clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) which is a common security threat. There might be a few things at play here.

1) The first thing I would check is that your site - `https://mcnabb--devsanbox.cs41.my.salesforce.com/` is a trusted site your browser. Just make sure that it opens normally (without an iFrame).

2) If the issues are specific to iFrame, try adding `target="_top"` and `&output=embed` for your iFrame in your .hjs file

3) Make sure your Click Jack protection settings are correctly configured. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BRJIA2) seems to be a similar issue to the one you posted.